# Trying to convert jpgs to video but getting only the first frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg, python, jpeg

*Update:*

Thanks to everyone who weighed in with help, I did finally get it to work.  My best understanding is that it was an issue with threading from the original script and the video creation command was running when only a single (or few) photos had been captured.  Here's how I changed the affected function.  Thank you!

```
def capture_image():
    try:
        global image_number

        total_images, interval = config["total_images"], config["interval"]

while image_number < total_images:

    # Start up the camera.
    camera = PiCamera()
    set_camera_options(camera)

    # Capture a picture.
    camera.capture(dir + "/image{0:05d}.jpg".format(image_number))
    camera.close()

            # if image_number < (config["total_images"] - 1):
            image_number += 1

            print(time.localtime(), image_number, total_images)

            time.sleep(interval)

        # else:
        print("\nTime-lapse capture complete!\n")
        # TODO: This doesn't pop user into the except block below :(.
        sys.exit()

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print("\nTime-lapse capture cancelled.\n")
```

*Original Question:*

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to compile a series of jpg stills into an mp4 within a Python script on a Raspberry Pi 3 B.  The command I'm attempting to run is as follows:

`ffmpeg -r 24 -i /home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_19-54-33/image%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 /home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_19-54-33-timelapse.mp4`

If I run that command from the command line on the Pi (or my Mac laptop) it works perfectly and outputs an ~8.6MB mp4 file.

The python script that I think is calling that command is as follows:

```
if config['create_video']:
    print '\nCreating video.\n'
    # os.system('avconv -framerate 20 -i ' + dir + '/image%05d.jpg -vf format=yuv420p ' + dir + '/timelapse.mp4')  # noqa
    command = (
        "ffmpeg -r 24 -i "
        + dir
        + "/image%05d.jpg"
        + " -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 "
        + dir
        + "-timelapse.mp4"
    )

    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

When I run this, it consistently outputs a ~200KB mp4 file that doesn't really play (in VLC).  My best guess is that it's only grabbing the first still image and is a 1/24th of a second long, single frame 'video.'  I'm running the script from the pi-timelapse folder and, despite it executing with the full path, I can't help but think the problem is in the %05 portion that should pull all of the images from the subfolder, relative to the cwd of the script.

Here's the terminal output:

```
pi@pi-timelapse:~/pi-timelapse $ python timelapse.py

Creating video.

ffmpeg version 4.1.6-1~deb10u1+rpt1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf --cpu=arm1176jzf-s --arch=arm
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avutil      configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avformat    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avdevice    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avfilter    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  avresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swscale     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  swresample  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  postproc    configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1+rpt1' --toolchain=hardened --incdir=/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-omx-rpi --enable-mmal --enable-neon --enable-rpi --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --libdir=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/neon/vfp --cpu=cortex-a7 --arch=armv6t2 --disable-thumb --enable-shared --disable-doc --disable-programs
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, image2, from '/home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_22-25-56/image%05d.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] using cpu capabilities: ARMv6 NEON
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] profile High, level 4.0
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_22-25-56-timelapse.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1920x1080, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
frame=    1 fps=0.9 q=28.0 Lsize=     158kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=16562359.0kbits/s speed=6.84e-05x    
video:157kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.498500%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] frame I:1     Avg QP:27.13  size:159993
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] mb I  I16..4:  3.6% 88.8%  7.6%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] 8x8 transform intra:88.8%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 86.6% 27.3% 2.1%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] i16 v,h,dc,p:  4%  4% 60% 32%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  8%  5% 54%  7%  6%  5%  5%  7%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 10%  6% 41% 10%  8%  7%  6%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] i8c dc,h,v,p: 73%  9% 16%  1%
[libx264 @ 0x10cb220] kb/s:31998.60

ffmpeg -r 24 -i /home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_22-25-56/image%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 /home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_22-25-56-timelapse.mp4


Time-lapse capture complete!
```

And this is the full script (mostly written by someone else - I'm just trying to convert the video writing function from avconv to ffmpeg):

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import errno
import os
import sys
import threading
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import yaml
import shlex
import pipes
from subprocess import check_call
import subprocess

config = yaml.safe_load(open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "config.yml")))
image_number = 0


def create_timestamped_dir(dir):
    try:
        os.makedirs(dir)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise


def set_camera_options(camera):
    # Set camera resolution.
    if config['resolution']:
        camera.resolution = (
            config['resolution']['width'],
            config['resolution']['height']
        )

    # Set ISO.
    if config['iso']:
        camera.iso = config['iso']

    # Set shutter speed.
    if config['shutter_speed']:
        camera.shutter_speed = config['shutter_speed']
        # Sleep to allow the shutter speed to take effect correctly.
        sleep(1)
        camera.exposure_mode = 'off'

    # Set white balance.
    if config['white_balance']:
        camera.awb_mode = 'off'
        camera.awb_gains = (
            config['white_balance']['red_gain'],
            config['white_balance']['blue_gain']
        )

    # Set camera rotation
    if config['rotation']:
        camera.rotation = config['rotation']

    return camera


def capture_image():
    try:
        global image_number

        # Set a timer to take another picture at the proper interval after this
        # picture is taken.
        if (image_number < (config['total_images'] - 1)):
            thread = threading.Timer(config['interval'], capture_image).start()

        # Start up the camera.
        camera = PiCamera()
        set_camera_options(camera)

        # Capture a picture.
        camera.capture(dir + '/image{0:05d}.jpg'.format(image_number))
        camera.close()

        if (image_number < (config['total_images'] - 1)):
            image_number += 1
        else:
            print '\nTime-lapse capture complete!\n'
            # TODO: This doesn't pop user into the except block below :(.
            sys.exit()

    except KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit:
        print '\nTime-lapse capture cancelled.\n'

# Create directory based on current timestamp.
dir = os.path.join(
    sys.path[0],
    'series-' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
)
create_timestamped_dir(dir)

# Kick off the capture process.
capture_image()

# TODO: These may not get called after the end of the threading process...
# Create an animated gif (Requires ImageMagick).
if config['create_gif']:
    print '\nCreating animated gif.\n'
    os.system('convert -delay 10 -loop 0 ' + dir + '/image*.jpg ' + dir + '-timelapse.gif')  # noqa

# Create a video (Requires avconv - which is basically ffmpeg).
if config['create_video']:
    print '\nCreating video.\n'
    # os.system('avconv -framerate 20 -i ' + dir + '/image%05d.jpg -vf format=yuv420p ' + dir + '/timelapse.mp4')  # noqa
    command = (
        "ffmpeg -r 24 -i "
        + dir
        + "/image%05d.jpg"
        + " -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25 "
        + dir
        + "-timelapse.mp4"
    )

    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    print("\n" + command + "\n")
```

Comment: Try disabling "Hardware-accelerated decoding" in VLC. Or use `ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i /home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_22-25-56/image%05d.jpg -c:v libx264 -vf fps=25,format=yuv420p /home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_22-25-56-timelapse.mp4`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think the problem is with the playing in VLC because the file sizes are drastically smaller than they'd need to be for a playable video.  I tried changing to the -framerate switch and then stripped the command down to only the essentials `ffmpeg -i image%05d.jpg timelapse.mp4` and they both work from the command line but falter being called via python script, this time with `os.system()`.  I then moved photos to the current directory and ran it successfully w/o the subdirectory so I'm even more convinced the problem is the %05 notation called by script from a subfolder.

Comment: What version of python?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded with the following command on a RPi 2B with python3

```
command = [
        "ffmpeg", "-r", "24",
        "-pattern_type", "glob", "-i", dir + "/20160205_1730???.JPG",
        "-c:v", "libx264", "-vf", "fps=25",
        "/tmp/" + "timelapse.mp4"
    ]
```

ffmpeg could'nt find my files when I tried the "%03d" pattern, even though a file like "20160205_1730430.JPG" existed.  But those errors were reported - in red - not hidden.

I couldn't watch the movie in my browser, but mplayer had no trouble, and reported:

```
Clip info:
 major_brand: isom
 minor_version: 512
 compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
 encoder: Lavf57.71.100
Load subtitles in /tmp/
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [x11] 2592x1944 => 2592x1944 Planar YV12 
[swscaler @ 0x55f9ace4d420]bicubic scaler, from yuv420p to bgra using MMXEXT
[swscaler @ 0x55f9ace4d420]using unscaled yuv420p -> bgra special converter
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that gives the same results (I did add a comma after the 24 and had to comment out `shell=True` within my code although I don't think those changed your intent).

Comment: And "ls -l  /home/pi/pi-timelapse/series-2020-11-03_22-25-56/image?????.jpg" gives you more than one file?

Comment: I wanted to try this myself, the only problem I had was with the "%03d" format (or "pattern_type").

Comment: Another minor inconvenience: after 50 JPG's, oom-killer kicks in.  From Python (an image earlier) as from commandline.  The images are 2592x1944, 1Mb in size.